# TCP is on top of IP, what does this mean?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming

I always hear about the layers of internet and i vaguely understand this. But, what confuse me most is that transport layer (including TCP protocol) lies on top of the internet layer(including IP protocol)..
What does this mean? For one who has a foggy understanding of the internet mechanism (I'm not a CS student or something I am just a hobby programmer)

The picture I have about the internet is that the network card sends/receives signals (packets) from the internet through wired connection / wifi then the OS using socket API sends/receives these packets acting as a layer between the hardware and the application which in turn uses some high-level protocol such as HTTP to interpret the data transferred - these protocol usually provided by languages e.g. python or java 
.. I guess then that IP and TCP protocol are used at the level of the socket API? but I need more details ? I hope the explanation be in terms of coding/programming/implementation because abstractions used in this area confuse me.

Thank you , and sorry for my bad English

Comment: It might help if you learn about [the OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Answer (score 2):

This is part of a layered solution to solve networking. Each layer has its own functionality:

- IP (Internet Protocol) is in charge of delivering a packet (or datagram) from one interface, in one machine, with an IP address assigned to another interface in the same or other machine (node). Both nodes can be in the same LAN or different LAN connected through different paths (LAN's and routers). Basically it will make the packet get from source IP to destination IP. It provides a best-effort services, it doesn't assure the IP packet is going to arrive, it can be lost in the middle.
- Above layer 3 or IP in the so-called TCP/IP stack, there is the transport layer. Its main functionality is to multiplex the lower layer (IP) service (take a packet from src to dst) among different applications. This is why in all transport layer protocols there is the concept of port or more generically Transport Service Access Point (TSAP). UDP, TCP, SCTP do that. UDP provides an unreliable service to the application. TCP provides a connected, reliable transport service to the application. This layer will make a message sent from application A in node Y reach application A1 in node Z, either reliably or unreliably (while IP only takes care of carrying the packet from node Y to node Z).

You will need to read a little about the OSI layered model and the TCP/IP layered model.

If you need to get more info I can address you to a training I have about IPv6 with a good introduction to networking: http://www.slideshare.net/rodolk/networking-tcpip-stack-introduction-ipv6

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a protocol, known as "Transmission Control Protocol" - by specification it has features in place which makes sure that transmitted data is checked. On the other hand, there are things such as UDP, aka "User Datagram Protocol" which also works on top of IP - by specification this method does not check any transmitted data, so it's less useful where files must be fully intact (more utilised for video streaming, where some lost frames is acceptable, as opposed to binary file transfers where incorrect data means corruption and the whole file would be useless).

On to IP, IP is an addressing protocol, allowing a network to address and communicate with any machine that lives within it. IP stands for Internet Protocol, and it defines the fundamental way that two machines communicate over the "internet". It does not define how communications are handled, in ways such as being checked for data integrity, etc.

So, to summarise, the TCP and UDP are just extensions of IP. It is entirely possible, however, to have a socket based TCP or UDP connection, and I expect it's also possible to have some sort of MAC address protocol (as opposed to an IP address protocol). I don't know of any protocols which are similar to IP, but I imagine they do exist. In reality, using TCP over something other than IP is entirely unlikely. If you're going to the effort to create a custom protocol, chances are you'll want it fully custom and won't want to stick to design specifications designed for another protocol layer.

Note that calling it a "TCP/IP" connection is probably only ever used for legacy reasons. A lot of terms like this still exist because before the technology "bubble" growth, there were competing alternatives to IP. Even today, there is IPv6 which is technically an alternative to IPv4. It's also possible that we might one day outgrow IPv6, and at that point in time, there could be something other than IP to worry about.